# Rails encryption S3 aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using the 'aws-sdk-s3' gem in rails 6, set up storage.yml

```
amazon:
   service: S3
   access_key_id: XXXX
   secret_access_key: XXXXX
   region: XXXX
   bucket: XXXX
```

How do I set to use encryption in s3?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-server-side-encryption.html

Comment: I believe you can turn it on at a bucket level, incidentally.

Comment: I think this game very good documentation where you have good description how to do it

Comment: So I'm using ActiveStorage directly using GEM ok .. but using ActiveStorage I'm not finding ways to solve

Comment: AES-256
Use server-side encryption with Amazon S3 managed keys (SSE-S3)